Unity - How to always keep application open in background
I am building an app where you can send and receive MQTT messages through topics. I am using unity and i have switched to android platform for this. My problem is that when i change app the code stop running, so it stops send / receive MQTT messages. When i open then app it works normally as expected.
What i tried and works on desktop is that there is an option on unity, Edit > Project Settings > Player > windows > Resolution and presentation , if you select the windows , it has an option, keep open on background.
It works perfectly on desktop when enabled. Even if i switch to another program it continues send / receive so assume code works. There is an asterisk on it that says *Shared setting for multiple platforms but it does not have an effect on my android phone.
Tried with Unity script to add
Application.runInBackground = true;

But it did not work as well for the app.
Any suggestion how to handle this would be more than welcome.
Unity Version 2022.3.30f1

Is it possible to do it with Android Manifest?
Can it start on startup in case phone restarts so it continue receive data?

My current Android Manifest where i use so it keeps the top bar enabled at all times
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.company.productname">
  <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
  <application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/UnityTransparentStatusBarTheme">
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.unity3d.nostatusbar.UnityPlayerActivityStatusBar" android:fitsSystemWindows="true" > <!-- Add android:fitsSystemWindows="true" here -->
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
    </activity>
  </application>
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
</manifest>



android and IOS kinda often fake apps being in background, and if not used, or they needed the memory will offload them, whether you like it or not, there is often not a lot you can specifically do to prevent that. I believe it is possible to create the equivelent of a windows service or unix daemon but, Ive not tried it

While i was searching i found this one link. I think i should create a service that runs in background.

Also this yt vid link
